# CF CLI features that are enabled in Bluemix

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

There are a lot of cloud foundry features provided by CF CLI, that Bluemix platform has decided to disallow.

CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT - Does not have any effect on Bluemix while uploading big war files.
cf set quotas - Does not work on Bluemix.
Delete organizations - Bluemix documentation says has to be done through support tickets.

Is there any documentation, what features will not work on Bluemix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not documented which features of the Cloud Foundry CLI are implemented in Bluemix and which ones are not - other than what is documented [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/). Some features, such as deleting organizations, can affect multiple things such as billing so that has to be done through support tickets.

Your best bet is to try whichever command you need from the [Cloud Foundry CLI](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/) or the [Bluemix documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/) and see if it accomplishes your task.

Also - in reference to Brian Martin's answer on this post, the privileges of a user account will affect the ability of certain commands to be run. Be sure to check you have admin privileges on the app/services you want to administrate.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the problem is not whether features are enabled or not, the problem is the CF cli has a combination of commands that are for administrators and others that are for non-admin users.   So some of the commands you listed (like set quota, create/delete org) require admin privileges to the system.   The CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT should be effective

Comment: Very good point - did not consider that. Is there are central place where CLI commands are listed with required permissions?